# the onNotificationOpened and getInitialNotification events are not triggered as I've used custom splash screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I am using react native firebase latest version and used a custom splash screen in android.
because of the custom splash screen, the onNotificationOpened and getInitialNotification events are not triggered.

https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1306

what should I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

see [this](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1306#issuecomment-457014645) GitHub issue, the solution works for me.

Comment: Please post relevant sections of the answer here itself as links might change over time.